# Receive and send a reply to another aodv node in omnet ++

Tags: omnet++, inet

I want to receive a message from a node R2 and return an answer, and calculate the delay from end to end of `msg`, for that I use the `sendDirect ()`. Here is the handlemessage code  in R1 (which must receive the msg) but the problem during simulation I managed to send the message from R2 to R1 but after the simulation stops and it displays:

> "unsupprted command,in module inet::physicalLayer::UnitDiskRadio)

Can anyone help me please?

```
void R1::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{ 

    if (strcmp(msg->getName(), "demande video") == 0)
     {
     eed1 = simTime() - msg->getTimestamp();
      cModule *m =  msg->getSenderModule();
       a = m->getId();
       data = new cMessage("reponse video");
        this->sendDirect(msg, m, "radioIn", 0);

       simtime_t eed2 = simTime() - data->getTimestamp();
       eed_total = eed2.dbl() + eed1.dbl();
```

Comment: Debug and step through each line see which line causes the crash/simulation to stop. Then dive deeper into either your own function that crashes or the third party api call and see if correct parameters are being passed. And possible could wrap things in try catch to prevent crashing. In this case it seems like you are missing some sort of library

Comment: Also ensure msg is not nullptr before continuing

Comment: Set `debug-on-errors=true` in your `omnetpp.ini` and then run your simulation in Debug mode. The debugger will show you the line which causes this error, an example is [here](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/part2/).